# symmetry in the homotopy relation

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose $\alpha, \beta : I \to X$ are paths and suppose $\alpha $ is homotopic to $\beta$, $\alpha \cong \beta$. So, can find a continuous function $F(s,t) = f_t(s)$ such that

$$ f_t(0) = \alpha(0) = \beta(0) = x_0 , \; \; \; f_t(1) = \alpha(1) = \beta(1) = x_1$$

Also, we know $f_0(s) = \alpha(s) $ and $f_1 = \beta$. We want to show $\beta \cong \alpha$. If we put $F(s, 1 - t) = f_{1-t}(s)$, then

$$ f_0(s) = \beta(s), \; \; \; \; f_1 = \alpha$$

so, $\beta \cong \alpha$ IS this correct? Any feedback?

Comment: @StefanH Although the questions are similar, this is asking for feedback and so *cannot* be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers at [Symmetry of "is homotopic to" detail in the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556411/symmetry-of-is-homotopic-to-detail-in-the-proof) give detailed proofs on why $H(x,t)=F(x,1-t)$ is continuous. The basic idea is that $H$ is the composition
$$I×I⟶I×I\longrightarrow X$$ where the first arrow is the map $(x,t)↦(x,1-t)$ and the second map is $F$. The first map again is continuous because its coordinates are.